# Spring Data Audit, CreatedBy lost on Update

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, audit

I have CreatedBy and UpdatedBy columns that are managed by Spring Data. Everything works well on persist, but When I update a row, the CreatedBy Column is set to Null. Is this expected behaviour? How can I instruct the update queries to not affect the CreatedBy Column?

Comment: add code for entities contains CreatedBy and code to save/update entity

Comment: @Hemant could you elaborate a bit? I don't want to preferable not fetch the entire data from the DB and modify that, I'd prefer to update using the primaryKey and data. If this is not advisable, please confirm that also. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit your post and add Code of class that have column `CreatedBy` and `UpdatedBy`. Also code from service class where you are saving entity into Database.